# No response when making REST request with same url but different http methods in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache, rest, apache-camel

I am newbie and working with Apache Camel and RESTful services. When I make request with same url but different http methods, I am getting

> CamelHttpTransportServlet - No consumer to service request org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade

This is my some content of web.xml

```
 <servlet>
   <display-name>Camel Http Transport Servlet</display-name>
   <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

This is the code for my RouteBuilder

```
  rest("/user").description("User rest service")
   .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
       .get("/{userId}").description("Get user with specified userId")
       .to("bean:userService?method=getUser(${header.userId})")

     .delete("/{userId}").description("Delete user with specified userId")
     .to("bean:userService?method=deleteUser(${header.userId})");
```

Now when I make the request in following order:

```
1)GET http://localhost:8090/foo/rest/user/3 
2)DELETE http://localhost:8090/foo/rest/user/3
```

During the first request I am getting the expected JSON data

```
 {
  "userName" : "test",
  "userId" : 3,
 }
```

Now when I call the second request `DELETE http://localhost:8090/foo/rest/user/3` after 
first one , it gives me following:

> CamelHttpTransportServlet - No consumer to service request org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@

So please If ayone can figure it out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is in the Servlet.

Please check that there is a method *deleteUser*.

Comment: I am not using servlet. There is bean which is servicing my request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are lacking a `.endRest()` route step after the `.to()` steps in your route builder.

Comment: thanx @Ralf for your time and reply. Did you mean in this way: 
.get("/{userId}").description("Get user with specified userId").route()
       .to("bean:userService?method=getUser(${header.userId})").endRest()

Comment: @PrashantMirchandani, yes, together with the route() step. But I think I was to rash with my answer. The endRest() should only be necessary if you are "embedding" routes in the REST DSL. As you have only one to() that should not be necessary. Have you tried to strip away all route steps except for the http-verb and the to()? Does it work then? Could be that one or more of the meta-data steps require you to embed a route.

Comment: What I noticed is first request type is working , for eg. when I make first request DELETE than it is working and then if I make GET request it doesn't works. Similarly when I first makes GET it works and when make DELETE then it doesn't works

Comment: @PrashantMirchandani, so does it work for the other verbs besides the first one if you strip away all other steps in the route?

Comment: .@Ralf I am not getting it. If you can elaborate it, by giving an example

Comment: @PrashantMirchandani, keep the route to the absolute minimum. See if it works that way. If yes, start adding the stuff back you removed until it breaks again: `rest("/user").get("/{userId}").to("bean:userService?method=getUser(${header.userId})").delete("/{userId}").to("bean:userService?method=deleteUser(${header.userId})");`

Comment: .@Ralf I am doing the same way you mentioned in your previous comment but still I am not getting it.

Comment: @PrashantMirchandani Have you tried the newly release 2.14.1? It [fixes](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7952) a bug that sounds like your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:
"The REST DSL will take care of duplicate path separators when using base path and uri templates. 
In the example above the rest base path ends with a slash ( / ) and the verb starts with a slash ( / ). 
But Apache Camel will take care of this and remove the duplicated slash."

works, if you write different names for the same uri:

```
rest("/user/{userId}")
.get().....
.delete("/").....
.post("//").....
```

Answer (score 0):

The same happens to me

```
[TRACE] org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service - Service: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@6388c915
[DEBUG] org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service - No consumer to service request org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@6388c915
```

My servlet in web.xml was configured like this:

```xml
<servlet>
  <display-name>Camel Http Transport Servlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>CamelServletMyApp</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>ignoreDuplicateServletName</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>    
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>CamelServletMyApp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The problem happens because the **servlet-name** is different from **CamelServlet**, as explain at [gotcha-when-using-camel](https://dzone.com/articles/gotcha-when-using-camel)

Back the **servlet-name** to **CamelServlet** to works.

```xml
<servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
```

I didn't get to works with a different name from CamelServlet :(